# easiest way to read all lines from all files in a directory in powershell

Tags: powershell

This expression seems to work:

```
gci . | % { gc $_}
```

This also seem to work as well (I suspect it is a little slower):

```
gci . | Select-String .
```

Is there a better way of writing a expression to dump all lines from all files out in a directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you don't want to throw directories at Get-Content.  Try this to filter out dirs:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Get-Content
```

or using aliases:

```
gci | ?{!$_.PSIsContainer} | gc
```

Also note that Get-Content takes the filename as pipeline input so you don't need the Foreach-Object cmdlet.  You can pipe directly to Get-Content.

Comment: good point.. I think you answered my question I can just use gci | gc instead of the | % {$_} construct which seemed a bit cumbersome thanks

Comment: I take it that the dir you're listing contains no directories?  If not then `gci | gc` will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Won't this one do?

```
gc * -ea SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: I generally like to avoid errors (even though you can suppress them with `-ea 0`). However, if there are no dirs then `gc *` is the way to go.